# Unable to profile using Instruments on iPad 1 using XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an application built against iOS 7, but targeted for iOS 5.1 since I only have an iPad 1 available for testing. It's an all native library, with very minimal iOS dependencies. I am able to run the app on my iPad just fine, but when I try to Profile it, XCode 5 immediately changes the status to 'Finished running  on iPad', and the Instruments window shows a warning saying 'This device does not support this instrument'. I see this behavior regardless of which instrument I choose from the Instruments panel.

I have tried other suggestions from similar issues posted on Stackoverflow such as
1. Cleaning my app and rebuilding
2. Restarting XCode
3. Deleting my app from the device
4. Changing the deployment target from 'iPhone/iPad' to just 'iPhone'

None of these have helped me get over this problem. Is there something fundamentally not supported in the configuration that I am trying to run ? Since the app runs correctly on the iPad, this seems like just a problem with Instruments compatibility, so I welcome any comments / suggestions on resolving this.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you either need a newer iOS device, or go back to an old version of Xcode/Instruments from the era when the iPad 1 was current technology.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR. Will try this with XCode 4